# How to assign code in table of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms

Is possible that i can get an alghorithm that was wrote in LaTeX with a package and transform in a figure to be added in list of figures (`\listoffigures`)?

Comment: Can you mock up an example of what you mean? Specifically, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two possibilities.

In both cases the trick is to use the float specifier `H` for the `algorithm` environment so to avoid it to float. In this way you can place it inside a `figure` environment.

---

### With `algorithm2e`

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\bigskip

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \KwData{this text}
    \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
    initialization\;
    \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
    go to next section\;
    current section becomes this one\;
    }{
    go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
    }
    \caption{How to write algorithms}
  \end{algorithm}
  \caption{My algorithm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### With `algorithmicx`

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\bigskip

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
      \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
  \caption{My algorithm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @LuizFilipe you're welcome.